# Enroll a data constructor field to a class

Tags: haskell

These are my declarations:

```
data CSV = String
data Table = [[String]]

write_csv :: Table -> CSV
read_csv :: CSV -> Table

data QResult = CSV CSV | Table Table | List [String]
data Query = FromCSV CSV | ToCSV Query

class Eval a where
    eval :: a -> QResult

instance Eval Query where
    eval (FromCSV csv) = QResult (read_csv csv)
    eval (ToCSV table) = QResult (write_csv table)
```

This is my code  and the last 3 lines when I try to enroll Query in Eval are the ones giving me an error. If I use `QResult` I get `Data constructor not in scope`, and if I leave it without `QResult` I get `Couldn't match type Table with QResult` and `Couldn't match type CSV with QResult`.

Comment: Your `Query` type doesn't make much sense. Every query is just a `FromCSV` value wrapped in zero or more `ToCSV` layers. Every `Query` can be trivially reduced to a single `CSV` value.

Comment: @chepner The ```Query``` type is much bigger, I just wrote those 2 values since I'm just starting it and want to know why it gives me an error.

Comment: `QResult` isn't a data constructor; it's a type constructor. You can't apply it to the return value of either `write_csv` or `read_csv`. You have to use `CSV`, `Table`, or `List` as appropriate.

Comment: @chepner Well both functions return a Table or a CSV, but even if I remove the ```QResult``` it still gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QResult` is  type constructor, not a data constructor. You need to use one of its data constructors to create the return value of `eval`.

```
instance Eval Query where
    eval (FromCSV csv) = Table (read_csv csv)
    eval (ToCSV table) = CSV (write_csv table)
```

`Table :: Table -> QResult` is the data constructor that you can apply to the return value of `read_csv`.

`CSV :: CSV -> QResult` is the data constructor that you can apply to the return value of `write_csv`.

The context is always sufficient to determine if a type constructor or a data constructor is needed, which is why you can reuse names for each.

---

The type constructors `Table` and `CSV` should be defined using the `type` keyword

```
type CSV = String
type Table = [[String]]
```